# Dissallow application to be referenced...?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make it so that my application cannot be used as a reference in other visual c# projects? My application was built using Visual C#, if you needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Just don't make anything public. What are you trying to prevent?

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply disallow another application from referencing your DLLs.

If you wanted to make it harder to use though, you could make all your methods and classes private or internal. If you have assemblies that need to reference it, you can make them friend assemblies, which would give them access to your internals. You could also take a look at obfuscating your code [using these free .NET obfuscators](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/09/15/free-net-obfuscation-tools/).

Comment: Won't signing your assemblies also help for this?

Comment: If you use it along with InternalsVisibleTo, yes, I believe it would.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to prevent others from using you assemblies if they can get they hands on them somehow. Obfuscation will make it harder (but not impossible) to reverse engineer the code, but if they just want to rip of your functionality even obfuscation isn't going to cut it. Using access modifiers will prevent others from using your code directly, but they can still access and call methods through reflection.

With that being said, you should probably also keep in mind that unless your assemblies can predict tomorrows stock prices the risk of someone actually using them without your permission may not be as big as you think. There are a lot of free libraries out there, so why would anyone go through the trouble of using your assemblies if they can get something similar for free?